# Cakephp redirect in isAuthorized method not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

So after login in isAuthorized method I'm trying to redirect user based on a condition. But problem is it's not redirecting. Below the code that I have tried.

```
protected function isAuthorized($LoginUser)
{   

        if ($this->getTable('Users')->hasCompany($LoginUser) == false){
            $this->redirect(['controller'=>'Companies','action'=>'edit']);
            dd("hello");
        }
}
```

It's not redirecting and getting hello message. How can I redirect after login user to another page based on condition ?

Comment: You're not supposed to do redirects from that callback, but only to return a boolean. Also note that you should _never_ die in a controller, this just messes up everything, the headers, the test environment, etc... It might help to find a solution if you elaborate on the context of this, _why_ do you need to redirect users at that point? Is there also a reason why you're not using the new authentication/authorization plugins?

Comment: @ndm Here the case is if a login user has no company information then after login the user will always redirect to company add page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the auth component's authorization objects are supposed to return a boolean, and depending on that, let the component do the unauthorized handling-

What you could do, is for example dynamically set the component's `unauthorizedRedirect` option (and probably also `authError`) from the controller's authorization handler for that specific case (I guess you'd also have to exclude the respective company controller's action from that check, as otherwise you'll end up in an infinite redirect loop):

```php
if (!$this->getTable('Users')->hasCompany($LoginUser)) {
    $message = __('You must provide company information in order to proceed.');
    
    $url = \Cake\Routing\Router::url([
        'controller' => 'Companies',
        'action' => 'add'
    ]);
    
    $this->Auth->setConfig([
        'authError' => $message,
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => $url,
    ]);
    
    return false;
}

// ...

return true;
```

If you find yourself in a situation where there's no such possibility, brute forcing a redirect by throwing a `\Cake\Http\Exception\RedirectException` *could* be a solution too, even though it's ideally avoided, it's better than dying, as it will at least emit a clean redirect response:

```php
$url = \Cake\Routing\Router::url([
    'controller' => 'Companies',
    'action' => 'add'
]);
throw new \Cake\Http\Exception\RedirectException($url);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > AuthComponent > Configuration options](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuration-options)**